# Is the Arens-Fort Space Compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

thanks in advance. My question is this:

Is the Arens-Fort space $X \; = \; (\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}) \cup \lbrace \omega \rbrace$ compact?

What I have so long is this:

Since we know that if a space is compact then it is locally compact, we know that $(0,0)$ is not locally compact so we know that Arens-Fort is not compact. But I don't know how to show a neiborghood of $(0,0)$ that is compact.

Comment: According to [Spacebook](http://www.austinmohr.com/spacebook) (based on Steen and Seebach's *Counterexamples in Topology*), the Arens-Fort space is not compact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** To show that $X$ is not compact, recall that the (open) neighbourhoods $U$ of $\omega$ have the property that $$\{ m \in \mathbb{N} : | \mathbb{N} \setminus  \{ n \in \mathbb{N} : \langle m , n \rangle \in U \} | = \aleph_0 \} \text{ is finite.}$$  Also, the points of $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ are isolated. So construct an open cover of $X$ which consists of an open neighbourhood $U$ of $\omega$ such that $X \setminus U$ is infinite, and all of the singletons missed by $U$.  (No proper subfamily of such a cover could cover $X$, because its elements are pairwise disjoint.)

Using a similar argument you can show that no neighbourhood of $\omega$ is compact.